# how can i filter/show results as i enter my query in to a search field?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, web

I need to try and create a search field that displays results as you are typing in your location.

For example, on the Commonwealth Bank website when looking for a branch (http://www.commbank.com.au/locate-us/), you will see that as you enter in a postcode or suburb name, the list of options that currently match your criteria are appearing and as you type more, it reduces down to match.

I have a full list of all states, suburbs & postcodes of Australia exactly as Commonwealth Bank but I need to direct the customer to a different web page showing the relevant information, not show a location on a map.

Is a plugin available that I can adapt or is this something that needs setup & coding by someone who knows what they are doing?

Comment: its called "**Autocomplete**" and there are hundreds of scripts around. This one is probably one of the most used: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't think of what it was called. Amazing how sometimes its harder to explain something so simple when all you needed was 1 word! :-)